# Python flask - change template when a button is clicked

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to change templates when a button is clicked.

Here is my python code:

```
@app.route("/", methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def my_forum_post():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['myBtn'] == 'Sign in':
            return render_template('new_profile.html')
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<form method = 'POST'>
      <input type="button" name="myBtn"  value="Sign in">
</form>
```

And the template which i want to swich to is called: new_profile.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line of your code:

```
text = request.form('input')
```

Change it to this:

```
text = request.form['input']
```

or this

```
text = request.form.get('input')
```